# Stop Bootstrap spinner to make it static and not spin

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. When an event begins, I can get the spinner to spin using the following:

```
<span class='spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-primary' role='status' aria-hidden='true' id='spinner' style='display: none'></span>
```

```
document.getElementById('spinner).style.display = 'inline-block';
```

But how do I stop it spinning? I don't want to hide the spinner because I want to display the static image. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The solution is quite simple. All you have to do is set `animation` to `none`:

```js
document.getElementById('spinner').style.animation = 'none';
```

### Demo

Below is a code snippet to demo it. The spinner will stop after `2s` of running.

```js
// Get the spinner element
var spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');

// Show the spinner
spinner.style.display = 'inline-block';

// Set a timeout of 2 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  // Stop the spinner animation
  spinner.style.animation = 'none';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<span class='spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-primary' role='status' aria-hidden='true' id='spinner' style='display: none'></span>





<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

## Edits

### Edit #1: whole circle displays

As I have said in comments, the spinner is not full circle in the first place. So a round about way is, when spinner has to be stopped, change the classist to of an icon of `FontAwesome` so that, the requested icon will show.

To do that first include the cdn:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

In font awesome 6, circle icon is `<i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i>`, so we replace the current `className` of spinner with `'fa-regular fa-circle'` in JS.

```js
document.getElementById('spinner').className = "fa-regular fa-circle";
```

#### Demo

Here in demo, The spinner will stop after `2s` of running and change icon (I have changed the icon to `check` and green color by `text-success` class - but you can use whatever you want, the process is same).

### Edit #2: Better way to handle animations

As per the comment by `@Yogi` yeah the other solution is more sophisticated but I don't think that the `@user1753640` wanted to restart animation, since he is asking for changing the icon to full circle at the end of spin. Still, if they do want to, then I also recommend to use `spinner.style.animationIterationCount` to stop and restart the spinner where the value of `0` stops and value of `Infinite` starts the animation.

Comment: Thanks! I want to use ```class="spinner-grow"```. When I stop the animation, the static image is bank. Is there a way of stopping it at an exact point so that the whole circle displays?

Comment: That won't happen. That is because the spinner is not full circle in the first place. SO when stopped it can't be made full circle. But instead you can replace the spinner with a circle icon from bootstrap icon

Comment: @user1753640 I have given how to change the icon in the answer now

Answer (score 2):

To stop the animation you can set the iteration count to 0

```
document.getElementById("spinner").style.animationIterationCount = 0
```

To continue the animation simply set it back to its original value

```
document.getElementById("spinner").style.animationIterationCount = 'Infinite'
```